# Run Ionic 5 app on real android device using capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, deploying

I've recently started working with capacitor using using ionic 5. I've read all the capacitor documentation but I didn't find any guidance that how can I run Ionic 5 app on real android device. Can anyone guide me how can run Ionic 5 app on real android device? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Since Capacitor 3 there is a run command

```
npx cap run android
```

It will show you a list of available devices/emulators to choose where you want to run.

Old answer:

Capacitor apps are run from Android Studio directly

If you already have an Ionic project with Capacitor integrated, just run `npx cap open` to open Android Studio, and with a device plugged, do `Run -> Run 'app'` or click the green triangle button.

Answer (score 2):

You can run ionic 5 on real android device with command:

```
$ ionic capacitor run android --target [device-id]
```

To get real android device-id, you can run this command:

```
$ adb devices
```

Example:

```
$ adb device
List of devices attached
05fca57a7d29    device

$ ionic capacitor run android --target 05fca57a7d29
> ng run app:build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the following command to run the app directly into the device.

What it will do is it will detect the connected device and ask you to select which device you want to run.

```
ionic capacitor run android --device
```