# How can i run ionic-capacitor app on Android-studio or mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to run an ionic-capacitor app on android studio or my android phone.

When i run

`ionic capacitor run android`

It shows:

**? Which device would you like to target? (Use arrow keys)**
and it not showing me any option. i pressed the arrow key still nothing and when i pressed enter it shows:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

Then i tried

`ionic capacitor run android --open`
After compiling it shows:

**[capacitor] [error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?**

**[capacitor]         Attempted to open Android Studio at: /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh**

**[capacitor]         You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.**

I searched online on how to set CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH but i didnt see any solution.

Finally i also tried following the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717256/run-ionic-5-app-on-real-android-device-using-capacitor) in a Stackoverflow answer.

I run **adb device** to show my device ID

Then i tried

`ionic capacitor run android --target 0441925667003082`

It showed the following error:

**[ERROR] 0441925667003082 is not a valid Target ID.**

**Use the --list option to list all targets.**

I tried to use the `--list` to list all target but it showing **[INFO] No native targets found.** despite my android device being connected and showing in the adb devices.

What am i doing wrong in all this steps ?.

How can i run ionic-capacitor on android studio and on my mobile device ?.

Comment: You can try an emulated device. Start one from Android Studio or use Genymotion.

Comment: @ChrisG How can i start it from Android Studio?

Comment: Tools -> AVD Manager, then click "Create Virtual Device" in the bottom left corner to create a new virtual machine.

Comment: @ChrisG Afer choosing pixel 2 and cllicking next it showing **/dev/kvm not found** by the right..will this be an issue or i should proceed to download the system image?

Comment: @ChrisG have installed an new virtual device but am still facing this error `[capacitor] [error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
[capacitor]         Attempted to open Android Studio at: /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
[capacitor]         You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.` when i run **ionic capacitor run android --open**

Comment: Right, that error message seems pretty straightforward though. Here's a [guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/). Check if the environment var exists and set it if necessary.

Comment: @Chris G The link helped. I was able to add add it to my evironment variables and am not facing that error again.But am facing another manifest merger failed error in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I think it is an error that create a crashe but is not displayed.

This solution worked for me:

```
ionic capacitor sync

ionic capacitor open android
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your environmenent variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT points to the android sdk location.

Also try re-installing @capacitor/cli and native-run

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually capacitor sometimes not detect device even-though the device is connected. This is due to **authentication issue**.
2. To solve this, in **Developer options** tap on **revoke authentications/permissions** (verify with your phone).
3. Turn off **USB debugging**, turn on **USB debugging** and Try again.

Comment: i had to reauthenticate the USB thing, like you said. It worked after that. Thanks +`

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your global variable

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add end the list

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME~/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk/
```

CTRL + O + Enter

source ~/.bashrc

restart you computer

Answer (score 0):

command is **ionic cap open android** for Open project in Android Studio.

**ionic cap run android** for run project via android studio

**ionic cap run android --external** for liveReload but here need is both of devices connected on same network.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

Running this worked for me.

```
ionic capacitor sync
ionic capacitor run android
```

the list was perfectly showed after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. The problem is that I installed AndroidStudio in a random folder.

When you use `ionic capacitor run android --open` it appears in the `/usr/local/` directory. To solve the problem, just move the AndroidStudio installation to this location.